# What is the risk of damaging a car when parking it outside for 1 year in a subtropical climate?

Tags: paint, parking, detailing

I'm living in a Mediterranean climate (subtropical) for 1 year with a 2 year old BMW (black metallic paint, white leather) which I need to park outside (no garage or carport). It will spend perhaps half the day in the sunshine as there are walls and trees to the side which should provide shading at other times.

What is the risk of permanent damage to the vehicle from the environment that a garage would have otherwise protected from? And short of purchasing a carport, is there anything I can do to mitigate that damage? I should note that the vehicle has a Ceramic Pro coating, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always going to be a risk of damage to a car leaving it outside in the elements. There's no way anyone on here is going to be able to tell you your car is going to have xxx amount of damage or be completely fine, mainly because *every car is different* and *every climate changes from day to day*. Your car will be damaged *some*. Most likely it will be negligible, considering it is a newer vehicle.

Short of buying a car port or renting a garage space, the best you can do for your vehicle is to get a car cover. They range from cheap to expensive, but the better ones will be multi-layered with a soft cloth inner shell which prevents any kind of fine scratching on the paint (though the coating your car has on it may protect it from that). There are two big things you would be protecting your vehicle from: sun & moisture. The sun would be the most damaging to paint and interior. When I say  "moisture", I'm not talking about the stuff which falls from the sky, I'm talking about the moisture which forms from dew during temperature changes. It doesn't just fall on the paint ... it gets everywhere. If the vehicle is covered, it blocks about 90% (yah, that's a guess) of the areas where dew can form, which helps prevents metal corrosion and thus protects the vehicle.

A car cover is relatively cheap insurance. The biggest problem with them is the annoyance of putting them on and taking them off your vehicle. If used correctly, it will provide your vehicle with almost as much protection from the elements as a garage would.